# Does the word "pouserieren" exist in German language?

Tags: meaning, translation, literature

While reading German translations of Marquis de Sade's literature, particularly the books of Juliette and Justine, the word "pouserieren" is commonly used to indicate anal intercourse.

I've found this work in my print copy of "Juliette - oder Die Wonnen des Lasters Teil II" from Könekamp Verlag from 1995, and through a quick search in these following translations, available on Google Books: [(1)](https://books.google.de/books?id=3696DQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA254&ots=8W2gwAJBvu&dq=pouserieren&hl=de&pg=PA257#v=onepage&q=pouserieren&f=false), [(2)](https://books.google.de/books?id=slFEDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA183&ots=_Kw38LGbDH&dq=pouserieren&hl=de&pg=PA184#v=onepage&q=pouserieren&f=false), [(3)](https://books.google.de/books?id=Hj4DDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT148&ots=7N-2cvTOMF&dq=pouseriert&hl=de&pg=PT148#v=onepage&q=pouseriert&f=false), [(4)](https://books.google.de/books?id=jVFEDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA185&ots=_YRG_6ce7p&dq=pouseriert&hl=de&pg=PA186#v=onepage&q=pouseriert&f=false)

But while I've found this word in five different publications of de Sade's works, I have yet to find it used anywhere else, I did not even find a single dictionary entry about it. Is this just a case of one translater using his creative freedom and other's simply copying his newly coined word, without it ever managing to gain any acknowledgement outside of these translations?

Comment: Never heard it. I think it's intentionally left in "german french" for effect, or to confuse the censor.

Comment: Wenn du wirklich aus Deutschland bist (steht jedenfalls in deinem Profil), und Erotikliteratur auf Deutsch liest, dann vermute ich, dass deine Muttersprache Deutsch ist. Dann ist es aber für uns alle ein wenig ärgerlich, wenn du deine Frage in einer Fremdsprache stellst. Das hier ist ein DEUTSCH-Forum, in dem vornehmlich Menschen Fragen beantworten, deren Muttersprache Deutsch ist. Damit, dass du auf Englisch fragst, zwingst du uns nämlich dazu, in einer Fremdsprache zu antworten, was ich für ziemlich unsinnig halte. Für zukünftige Fragen: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/830/1487

Comment: @HubertSchölnast In dem verlinkten Beitrag schreibst Du, dass Du die Wahl dem Themenersteller überlassen willst und sprichst Empfehlungen aus. Ich finde die Entscheidung, auch als Muttersprachler auf Englisch zu schreiben, legitim. Englisch ist die Verkehrssprache und bei Q&A-Seiten steht ja die potenzielle Leserschaft im Vordergrund. Und die hier behandelten Fragen sind nicht per se nur für Leute interessant, die Deutsch können.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Genau 100% aller Menschen, die German.SE besuchen, sprechen Deutsch, oder haben ein Interesse daran, Deutsch zu lernen. Darunter sind möglicherweise auch Menschen, die außer Deutsch überhaupt keine andere Sprache sprechen (das trifft auf viele ältere Menschen zu). Andererseits gibt es keinen Grund anzunehmen, das hier alle Englisch sprechen. Ich habe hier z.B. Besucher gesehen, die aus dem arabischen Raum kommen, nicht Englisch sprechen, aber Deutsch lernen wollen.

Comment: (Forts.:) Ich stimme dir zu, dass viele der hier behandelten Fragen nicht nur für Leute interessant sind, die Deutsch können. Aber daraus lässt sich keinesfalls der Schluss ziehen, dass diese Leute alle Englisch sprechen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast In der verlinkten Meta-Frage steht in der akzeptierten (und auch mit-höchstbewerteten) Antwort *it's a matter of personal choice* - Ich würde vorschlagen, wir überlassen dem Fragenersteller die Entscheidung.

Comment: Vielen Dank für eure Rückmeldungen. Ja, ich bin Muttersprachler und lese auch die angegebene Literatur in Deutsch. Die Frage habe ich auf Englisch gestellt, da ich schlicht und ergreifend nicht wusste, dass Fragen auf Deutsch hier erlaubt/bevorzugt sind; Diskussionen zu dieser Problematik scheint es im zugehörigen Meta-Bereich einige zu geben. Letztendlich ließe sich argumentieren, dass es bei einer Frage zu Übersetzungen nicht falsch ist, die Frage in der anerkannten Weltsprache zu formulieren; allerdings ist es ja eine Übersetzung aus dem Französischen, also greift das Argument nur bedingt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Just because this StackExchange is about the German language doesn't mean it's a German site.  The rules you linked to are not rules - they are guidelines which you came up with and not a single person here is required to follow them.  If the OP wants to post his question in English, he can do that.  Just because you may not be comfortable speaking English does not mean that other people are 100% comfortable speaking German.

Answer (score 8):

I'm unfamiliar with the word. It is **not** the original French word used by de Sade (according to a spot check I made, the French word used in the original is *enculer*, which is perfectly straightforward, even though it's decidedly not to be used in polite company).

All the "translations" you cite are actually different edition of a single 1906 translation by [Martin Isenbiel](http://mchealth.info/lexikon-5/i/Isenbiel.htm) (a prolific and polyglot translator of erotica, who is also credited for a translation of *Fanny Hill*), so it's unsurprising that they would have used the same word. Since that translation is in the public domain, it's conveniently republishable.

So the word may either be early 20th century Viennese slang, or entirely made up by the translator.

Answer (score 7):

The word »pouserieren« is not a word of Standard German vocabulary, but it is not completely unknown.

When reading high quality erotic literature, you often find exotic words to describe different sexual practices. This is to avoid the repeated use of the same few words while you describe a certain action in more than just one short paragraph. Another reason for using exotic words is to give the situation you want to describe an exotic touch.

I guess, that you will not find the word in any other written German text than in the translations of Marquis de Sade.

But this word was adopted in spoken German, at least in some dialects. For example in the east of Austria this word is well understood:

> **Buserer**, der
>   [busara]
>
> Bedeutung:
>
> - Stoß von hinten
> - indirekter Stoß beim Karambolspiel

Quelle: [Wienerisches Wörterbuch](http://www.echtwien.at/home/literatur/lexikon/B/1106)

> my translation of the meanings:
>
> - a push from behind
> - indirect stroke at carom billards

The writing is different (there is no standardized orthography for dialect words), but since it sounds very similar, and has a very similar meaning (push from behind), I am pretty sure, that this dialect word derives from the word you found in your book.

Answer (score 1):

I admit, this is not a full answer; but I thought it might be worth sharing anyway.

[Your copy of de Sade's work might be a simple reprint of an older translation.]

In the historic loanword-dictionary *Handbuch der Fremdwörter in der deutschen Schrift und Umgangssprache, zum Verstehen und Vermeiden jener, mehr oder weniger entbehrlichen Einmischungen, mit einem eingefügten Namendeuter und Verzeichniss fremder Wortkürzungen, nebst den Zeichen der Scheidekunst und der Sternenkunde, herausgegeben von Dr. Friedrich Erdmann Petri*, Leipzig Arnoldsche Buchhandlung 1865, p. 624, I found the entry:

> **Pousseur**, m., fr. (spr. pußöhr), ein Frauenjäger, Liebler

So maybe the verb was known as a loandword in earlier german. Today it seems to have vanished, as your own research is already proving.

Comment: There is still a verb **poussieren**, but it means "flirting", not anal intercourse.

Answer (score 0):

*Pouserieren* means to "urge" someone without violence. It has a similar meaning as "angehen".

Pouserieren was used as slang word in Vienna, especially when there is a 
special attraction for example to get in closer contact, male - female and 
the other way round.